# ServiceStack.Redis: PooledRedisClientManager creating way too many connections

Tags: c#, iis, redis, servicestack

I think I'm doing something wrong here. Before I start, a little bit of context.

Our company works with a tool called GeneXus: It's one of those code-generator tools, which has been used for years and years. It generates C# code so we can build our own assemblies and make it work with that tool. Our application deals a lot with SOAP calls, and it also makes some good use of Redis. In fact, Redis is a main piece of the whole code infrastructure.

To make it work with Genexus, we had to create a wrapper class around the ServiceStack.Redis library, so it can be used within our GeneXus code. That's how we use it inside GeneXus:

```
//First we check if Redis is working at all. It just pings the Redis server.
If &RedisClient.Check()

   //Here we make several calls to get and set some data. Like that:

   If &RedisClient.Exists("Some_Key")

       &MyData = &RedisClient.Get("Some_Key")

   Else      

       &MyData = FetchFromSQLServerDatabase()        
       &RedisClient.Set("Some_Key", &MyData)

   EndIf 

   //We are done with Redis, close it.

   &RedisClient.Close()

EndIf
```

That was a simple example, but our wrapper is consistently used like this: Check to see if it's online, do several things and then close the client.

The call to `.Close()` calls the `.Dispose()` method under the hood.

And this is how we manage the client creation in the wrapper.

First, we have a RedisProvider class which is a singleton. Doing some tests, we ensured that the pool is created only once. We create a pool instance like this, inside the singleton RedisProvider:

```
Pool = new PooledRedisClientManager(
    poolSize: poolSize,
    poolTimeOutSeconds: timeout,
    readWriteHosts: hosts);
```

and this RedisProvider class also has a method like this:

```
public RedisClient GetClient() => (RedisClient)Pool.GetClient();
```

**What we discovered so far:**

We did some tests using Apache JMeter against our SOAP webservice, simulating 50 users or so. This is what we discovered so far:

- The problem only happens inside an IIS ASP.NET application. Testing it on a Console Application with heavy concurrency fails to reproduce the problem.
- The pool itself is being created only once. The whole application shares this single instance.
- In the GeneXus example above, it's completely proven that a single connection is used across the calls, from `&RedisClient.Check()` to `&RedisClient.Close()`.
- **BUT** when another `&RedisClient.Check()` is called, normally another connection is created (and apparently it doesn't reuse the previously closed client) and we end up having thousands and thousands (assuming a pool limit of 5000) of TCP connections (which is kinda huge) in a `Close Wait` state, which don't get reused.
- When it hits the pool limit, we have some handling logic (which I didn't put here) to just create a new connection using `new RedisClient()` after the pool timeouts, which one might think it's not the smartest way to handle that, but well... It does that for a while, and then all those thousands of connections in a `Close Wait` state starts to close, and then the pool starts working again.

My question is: Why isn't it reusing the TCP connections? It works fine in a Console Application simulation, but when we put it to work on our Genexus application using IIS, it just keeps creating those connections.

Did I just got this pool thing wrong all the time, or am I doing something wrong?

Note: For now I'm providing all these info, but if you need more, no problem. I just don't know what more to provide.

Edit: Solved. My code was trying to be too smart. I dumbed it down and now it's working properly, though I still don't understand what I was doing wrong. Also, my assumption that absolutely all the connections to Redis were being closed right after being used turned out to be wrong.

Comment: 4 years later, how did u resolve it? I am experiencing the same issue now...

Comment: YOu can try using StackExchange.Redis instead @Ted

Comment: Nothing against ServiceStack.Redis, but the StackExchange one is free and open source. I actually had even worse problems with it, but I think that was due to our weird development environment and tech stack at the time. Things have evolved a lot since then with asp.net core.

Comment: Whatever works =) Im my case, and if I remember correctly, StackExchanges lib was, according to some benchmarks, much much slower thatn ServiceStack. Also, StackExchange lacked some very important features for me. Since I am using ServiceStacks other libs/APIs, its natural for me to continue with it as far as it'll take me. The SS Redis lib is working well for me now, even though I have some feature requests every now and then. Mythz is very quick to answer questions and add features (that he agrees with) =)

Comment: Just for curiosity, here's a github issue I opened for SE.Redis (https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/437). Disregard the cringy writing :) Did you solve your original issue? It's been almost a year rofl... and in contrast to what you said, I always found SE.Redis to be way faster, probably due to async I/O. The free version of SS we used didn't have this feature, things must be different now.

Comment: Yes, when being diligent with the using statements, I think that was what resolved my problem. SS has since added async support to Redis API =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical usage pattern for accessing a client is to use a using statement, i.e:

```
using (var redis = redisManager.GetClient())
{
    //...
}
```

Calling `Dispose()` is what releases the client back into the pool.

#### Connection Pool Stats

You can view a snapshot of internal stats of the connection pool by printing out the Dictionary returned by `GetStats()`:

```
redisManager.GetStats().PrintDump();
```

#### [Redis Stats](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/Redis-Stats)

You can also view an overall stats of all Redis Client activity with the Global:

```
RedisStats.ToDictionary().PrintDump();
```

I'd also consider reducing your connection pool size as a connection pool of **5000** is close to not having a connection pool at. I'd be aiming for ~2-3x of your active connections.

Comment: I edited my question. We always call the .Close method when we're done, which calls the .Dispose() method of the ServiceStack RedisClient object. So it's just like if we were using the `using` statement. Again, this problem seems to be happening only within ASP.NET applications running on IIS, when simulated on a Console application with multiple threads, it doesn't happen.

About the connection pool stats, I'll try that.

About the pool size, I can't argue with that :D

Comment: Should I be able to keep using a RedisClient after I dispose it? I did a quick test and I was able to set a key after the client was disposed. Should that be possible?

Comment: Ok, solved. Turns out my code was trying to be too smart. I still don't understand what I was doing wrong, but I dumbed it down and it seems like it's behaving properly now.

Comment: Can you share your expirience? I have the same issue with IIS, even tough i stop the mqServer and use the using() stuff